# jQuery make a div come out behind an object and goes back into it effect

Tags: jquery

I have a div which includes a bunch of sentences and another div which contains an image. When hovering on the sun, I want the words to come out from behind the sun and hovering out, go back into the sun. I don't get the desired effect with `.show()` and `.hide()`. The words will keep on rotating while the sun is being hovered.

Here is the picture.

[image]

I am trying the implement whereas the words will appear from behind from the center of the sun and vice versa when hovering out.

Any idea how to implement the mentioned effect? Here is my current code. Thanks much!

```
$sun.hover(function(e) {
    $txt.show('slow');

    // text rotation
    var counter = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (counter != -360) {
            counter -= 1;
            $txt.css({
                MozTransform: 'rotate(-' + -counter + 'deg)',
                WebkitTransform: 'rotate(-' + -counter + 'deg)',
                transform: 'rotate(-' + -counter + 'deg)',
            });
        }
    }, 20);

}, function(e) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $txt.hide('slow');

});
```

Comment: **Theorically**
those words would need to be nested inside a div which is positioned in center (margin:0 auto) with width and height which would be less than the size (verticall-horizontal) of the sun,
hovering the sun would activate .hover method and animate the width + height of the div element to greater than the default values.. and on hover out reset the height-width back to normal
i havent try this but let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the css3 `background-size` :

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/imehum/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var $sun = $('#sun');
var $txt = $('#text');
var intvl;
var c = 0;

    $sun.hover(function(e){
      
        clearInterval(intvl);
        intvl = setInterval(function() {
            if (c != -360) {
                c += 1;
                $txt.css({
                    MozTransform: 'rotate(-'+c+'deg)',
                    WebkitTransform: 'rotate(-'+c+'deg)',
                    transform: 'rotate(-'+c+'deg)'
                });
            }
        }, 20);
      $txt.stop().animate({backgroundSize:'100%', opacity:'1'},700);
    }, function(){
        clearInterval(intvl);
        $txt.stop().animate({backgroundSize:'60%', opacity:'0.1'},400);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The **z-index** property may be useful here.

In the simple example below, the text is initially set behind the image. When the mouse hovers over the image, the z-index value of the text is *moved up*.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function showCaption(){
          $(".caption").css("z-index","3");
       }
       function hideCaption(){
          $(".caption").css("z-index","1");
       }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #container{ position:relative; }
        .image{ position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:2; }
        .caption{ position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="image" onmouseover="showCaption();" onmouseout="hideCaption();">
            <img src="bill-gates-ms.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            Some text here and here.
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```